# Drive re-partitioning how do i add the unallocated space to dev sda2?

Tags: partitioning, windows, 13.10, drive, resize

Here is what my drives look like:
[image: gparted screenshot]

sda2 is a windows drive and sda6 is ubuntu.

Not necessarily using gparted, what is the best way to extend sda2 so that is had the unallocated space added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Easy.  You will need to slide sda6 over into the unallocated space(which puts the free space between sda2 and sda6), then increase the size of sda2.   It is simple to do GParted:  right-click sda6 and choose Resize/Mov.  Increase the "space preceding" value and decrease the "space following" value.  It's easier just to slide the right side black arrow and the left side black arrow to the right.  This moves sda6 to the right.  Then do the same for sda2, but instead of moving the whole partition, you will just move the right-side black arrow to increase its size.

One gotcha, you can only move/resize unmounted partitions and sda2 will be mounted since you will be running GParted from Ubuntu.  So take the disc from which you installed Ubuntu and boot to "Live CD" mode.  It has GParted already installed and you can then move any and all partitions of your hdd.

Enjoy!